# Keycloak docker service cannot connect to database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, containers, keycloak

I am new to docker and I want to start a keycloak container with docker-compose. I am using a mariadb and database starts successfully. But when starting keycloak container it gives this error.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=project-db)(port=3308)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:project-db, port:3308. Connection refused (Connection refused)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:241)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1243)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:622)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:142)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:86)
> at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
> ... 57 more
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:project-db, port:3308. Connection refused (Connection refused)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:241)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:87)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createSocket(tocol.java:218)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:474)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1238)
> ... 61 more
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
> at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createSocket(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:213)
> ... 63 more

This is my docker-compose.

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  project-db:
    container_name: project-maria-db
    image: mariadb:10.5.8-focal
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    volumes:
      - /project/db:/data/db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=project
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password

  project-keycloak:
    container_name: project-keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8180:8080
    environment:
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      DB_VENDOR: mariadb
      DB_ADDR: project-db
      DB_PORT: 3308
      DB_DATABASE: project_keycloak
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    depends_on:
      - project-db
```

can someone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add network to combine them in same network.

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  project-db:
    container_name: project-maria-db
    image: mariadb:10.5.8-focal
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    volumes:
      - /project/db:/data/db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=project
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - app-network

  project-keycloak:
    container_name: project-keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8180:8080
    environment:
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      DB_VENDOR: mariadb
      DB_ADDR: project-db
      DB_PORT: 3308
      DB_DATABASE: project_keycloak
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    depends_on:
      - project-db
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```